# Find and Replace string and what's following it

Tags: regex, sed

I have the following links in a sql dump file(.sql).
I need to use 'sed or grep with regex' or something to replace each occurance of
 `#cheese-pasta=` and whatever is after it including slash.

Example:

```
 <a href="somelink/#cheese-pasta=2011-13\">
  <a href="somelink/#cheese-pasta=\">
```

After the replacement, this will look like:

```
<a href="somelink/">
```

I could jus do somethin like `sed /#cheese-pasta=/ /g`
but, problem is that string is followed by other stuff and i want replace the stuff that's following it upto the quote that ends the link tag ()

Thanks a lot.

Comment: To clarify, you want to replace everything _inside_ the href attribute, or everything up to the end of the tag `>`

Comment: Hi Michael,I want replace the string "#cheese-pasta=" and whatever is following it upto the quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write:

```
sed 's/#cheese-pasta=[^\\]*\\//g'
```

which will replace `#cheese-pasta=`, followed by zero or more characters that *aren't* backslashes, followed by a backslash.

Alternatively:

```
sed 's/#cheese-pasta=[^"]*"/"/g'
```

(same concept, but using `"` instead of `\` to find the end of the text to replace).

Comment: Thank you Ruakh. This does it. If i can ask you two questions. (1) where can i see documentation for this, specially using [^\\]? (2) if i don't want the last slash "\" replaced how to midify this. I tried couple of variations already & they don't seem to work. Thanks again

Comment: (1) `sed` uses POSIX Basic Regular Expressions ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions); [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03)). (2) You can write either `sed 's/#cheese-pasta=[^\\]*//g'` (to replace "`#cheese-pasta=` plus zero or more non-backslash characters" with "nothing") or `sed 's/#cheese-pasta=[^\\]*\\/\\/g'` (to replace "`#cheese-pasta=` plus zero or more non-backslash characters plus one backslash" with "one backslash").